# findbyIdAndUpdate not working when there is addition of records in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

I have wrote a update query which will find the record by _id and update. This code is completely working fine until If I add a new record in that collection. If add a record and do a query it goes to success part but returns null instead of the data. But when I restart the code and try same operation, it's working fine. My method is PUT.

```
accept = (req, res) => {
var query = { _id: req.params.uid };
var updatevalue = { $set: { status: 3 } };
var options = { new: true }
this._model.findByIdAndUpdate(query, updatevalue, options, (err, obj) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
       res.send(obj);

    }
});
```

}

**Request**

```
api.abc.com/api/accept/5cfe4dd898fd225ef1cabdsd
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to cast the uid to ObjectId as Mongoose implicitly converts it under the hood, just do `user: req.params.uid` in your query

Comment: user is a objectid that doesn't matter ?

Comment: What "restart the code" mean? Restart the server or you change something in the code and then reset it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually, we can update a single record in multiple ways

1. [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method is used for update a record in collection.
   It is okay to use this method, instead of manually finding the record and then updating it.
   This method works really faster than the manual method.
   It has an option flag `new`, if it is true it will return an updated record in the response.

```
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id},{$set:{name:user.name}},{new:true}).then((docs)=>{
        if(docs) {
           resolve({success:true,data:docs});
        } else {
           reject({success:false,data:"no such user exist"});
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{
       reject(err);
    });
```

2. [findByIdAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) method is used to update record based on Id.
   Where we can pass the id as `«Object|Number|String»` value of _id to query. So here, directly we can pass `req.params.id`

```
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set:{name:user.name}},{new:true}).then((docs)=>{
       if(docs) {
         resolve({success:true,data:docs});
       } else {
         reject({success:false,data:"no such user exist"});
       }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        reject(err);
    })
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, 
am trying findByIdAndUpdate 

*** const updated =  Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.product._id, 
    {$set:filteredBody}, {
          new: true,
          runValidators: true
        }); ***
but it doesn't updated , please let me know what i did wrong

Comment: please go this document https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Answer (score 3):

Although you [don't have to pass `id` in the form of an object](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) it seems the culprit is in `req.params.uid`.
Double-check if `uid` is really set on the `req.params` and it's correct in a sense that it points to a document in your collection.
For the moment that's the only obvious reason that explains why you get `null` back.
You can check that through mongo shell using [`db.collection.find(<query>)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find).

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of `findByIdAndUpdate` doesn't seem to be correct, the first argument is supposed to be an id (mongodb object ID or just a string) instead of an object. I would try this first

```
this._model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.uid, updatevalue, options, (err, obj) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
       res.send(obj);

    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `query` as the filter in your code, then you can use `findOneAndUpdate` instead. Detailed doc is [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate).